# What is the difference between Send and 'static on a closure in rust?

Tags: rust

Consider these structs:

```
struct Promise1<T, Err> {
    on_resolve:Option<|promised:T|: Send>,
    on_reject:Option<|failed:Err|: Send>,
}

struct Promise2<T, Err> {
    on_resolve:Option<|promised:T|: 'static>,
    on_reject:Option<|failed:Err|: 'static>,
}

struct Promise3<'a, T, Err> {
    on_resolve:Option<|promised:T|: 'a>,
    on_reject:Option<|failed:Err|: 'a>,
}
```

Tangibly, what is the difference between them?

What is 'Send' as a bound, and why when providing Send, do I no longer have to provide a lifetime? What is this implicit lifetime that Send is generating?

Specifically, what is the difference between Send and 'static as closure bounds.

For example, this works:

```
let k:|int|:Send = |i:int| {};
let p:|int|:Send = |i:int| {};
Promise1 {
    on_resolve:Some(k),
    on_reject:Some(p)
};
```

But this does not:

```
let k = |i:int| {};
let p = |i:int| {};
Promise1 {
    on_resolve:Some(k),
    on_reject:Some(p)
};
```

Error:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `core::option::Option<'static |_|:Send>`, found 
`core::option::Option<|int|>` (expected bounds `Send`, found no bounds)
```

...however, this works fine using Promise2 or Promise3 with 'static and 'a respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Send` is a 'kind' http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#built-in-traits

> send : Able to be sent across task boundaries.

`'static` is a lifetime that's special: a lifetime that lasts for the entire program.

The reference also contains another illuminating section on `Send`: (we haven't gotten an optimal layout for the reference yet) http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#type-kinds

> Send : Types of this kind can be safely sent between tasks. This kind includes scalars, boxes, procs, and structural types containing only other owned types. All Send types are 'static.

So that's why you can use them interchangeably in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are we talking about a lifetime?

A closure embeds an environment, which may or not contain references to the current thread stack. This environment has a lifetime bound, which indicates the maximum duration for which it is viable and corresponds to the shortest lifetime of any embedded reference, which you indicate with the appropriate notation.

- if it contains a reference to the current thread stack, then the lifetime of the closure should not exceed the lifetime of said reference
- if it contains a reference to a static resource, and is not linked to the thread stack thus, then the lifetime of the closure is not limited

`'static` is the upper bound, since it gives no restriction, and therefore `'static` is used to indicate the absence of any lifetime constraint. It neatly avoid a special case: there is always a lifetime bound, it is just that sometimes it's "infinite".

> What does `Send` mean?

The `Send` kind is applied to an object to indicate it can be sent to another thread safely, for example via a channel. It implies, thus, that said object carries no reference to the current thread stack, as otherwise should the stack unwind the object would contain dangling references!

> Why does `Send` seem to imply `'static`?

1. If an object has no reference to the current stack, its lifetime bound is `'static`
2. `Send` implies that an object has no reference to the current stack

It is trivial, therefore, that `Send` implies the lifetime bound of the object is `'static`.

> But...

There are actually safe ways to refer to another stack's reference, for example in fork-join parallelism where the thread being referred to ensures it outlives the threads borrowing references. It was [touched on here](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/06/11/data-parallelism-in-rust/), and seem to require different kinds than `Send` to precisely specify how the data can be safely shared.

Comment: Can you explain how `'static` works in regards to the ownership model and freeing memory? I am having trouble wrapping my head around what it means to pass an argument into a function with a static lifetime declared. Does the item that is passed in have to live for the life of the program? Is this a kind of memory leak?

Comment: After some experimentation, I *think* I get it... http://is.gd/8KWutk `'static` means that the given Trait is static -- not the item being passed in! This makes more sense.

Comment: @jocull: `'static` means "lifetime of the program". (1) `&'static T` means that this instance of `T` must lives as long as the program, it can be achieved either by leaking it (humpf...) or simply because it's a `static` constant. (2) `Trait + 'static` means that the item should not contain references with a lifetime of less than `'static`, it can be achieved either by only containing `&'static T` or by not containing any reference.